# Why terraform created load balancer cannot connect my backend?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to use terraform to made our infra management by code. But I met a really weird problem that I can not explain it at all.

At first, I can use terraform create a load balancer for my instance group and everything is the same as what I manually created in GCP console. No error reports. But that terraform load balancer cannot connect to backend. And the GCP logger reports 502 error which refers to something wrong with load balancer. But when I manually create a load balancer for my instance group at the same time, which means I put 2 load balancers in front of my instance group. One is created by terraform and the other one is created by hand. And when that manually created load balancer set up, both terraform load balancer and manually created load balancer can connect to my backend too and works fine. Even I delete that manually created load balancer, the terraform created load balancer can work too.

```
provider "google-beta" {
  credentials = file("cred.json")
  project = var.project_id
  region = var.region
  zone = var.zone
}

resource "google_compute_instance_template" "instance_template" {
  provider = "google-beta"
  name_prefix = "cadence-graphite-"
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  region = var.region

  disk {
    // Instance Templates reference disks by name, not self link
    source_image = "centos-7" 
    auto_delete = false
    boot        = false
  }


  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default-network"
  }

  metadata_startup_script = file("startup.sh")
}

resource "google_compute_instance_group_manager" "instance_group_manager" {
  provider = "google-beta"
  name               = "cadence-graphite-manager"
  base_instance_name = "cadence-graphite"
  zone               = var.zone

  version {
     name = "instance_group_manager"
     instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.instance_template.self_link
  }

  target_size       = "1"

  update_policy {
    type                  = "PROACTIVE"
    minimal_action        = "REPLACE"
    max_surge_fixed       = "1"
    max_unavailable_fixed = "1"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_health_check" "autohealing" {
  provider = "google-beta"
  name = "cadence-graphite-health-check"
  check_interval_sec  = 10
  timeout_sec         = 5
  healthy_threshold   = 2

  http_health_check {
    port         = "8080"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_backend_service" "backend" {
  provider = "google-beta"
  name = "cadence-graphite-backend"
  health_checks = [google_compute_health_check.autohealing.self_link]

  port_name = "http"
  protocol = "HTTP"
  timeout_sec = 30

  backend {
     group = google_compute_instance_group_manager.instance_group_manager.instance_group
     balancing_mode = "RATE"
     capacity_scaler = 0.4
     max_rate_per_instance = 50
  }

  security_policy = "cadence-secuirty-policy"
}

resource "google_compute_url_map" "url-map" {
  provider = "google-beta"
  name            = "cadence-graphite-url-map"
  default_service = google_compute_backend_service.backend.self_link
}

resource "google_compute_global_address" "cadence-graphite-external" {
  name = "cadence-gloable-graphite-ip"
}

resource "google_compute_target_http_proxy" "http-proxy" {
  provider = "google-beta"
  name        = "cadence-graphite-proxy"
  description = "http proxy for cadence graphite"
  url_map     = google_compute_url_map.url-map.self_link
}

resource "google_compute_global_forwarding_rule" "gloable-rules" {
  provider = "google-beta"
  name       = "global-cadence-graphite-lb"
  ip_address = google_compute_global_address.cadence-graphite-external.address

  load_balancing_scheme = "EXTERNAL"
  target     = google_compute_target_http_proxy.http-proxy.self_link
  port_range = "8080"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the issue comes from wrong backend set up. When I create backend service, I have to specify the named_port and this named_port should define in group_manager. Then the backend that I created can find out which port it can connect. This part is not mentioned in terraform documentation.